# basic usage of pthread function with return value

Tags: c, pthreads

I am trying to create a thread that can read the number of lines in a file when called from main.c

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_FILE_NAME 100
#include "t_func.h"
#include <pthread.h>
int main(){
    int linecount;
    pthread_t thread_id;
    FILE *fh = fopen("/home/usr154/out.log", "r");
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, count_lines,&fh);
    pthread_join(thread_id, (void **) linecount);
    printf("lines: %d \n", linecount);
}
```

t_func.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int count_lines(int *fh){
    char c;
    int count =0;
    if (fh == NULL)
        {
            printf("Could not open file %s", fh);
            return 0;
        }
    for (c = getc(fh); c != EOF; c = getc(fh))
        if (c == '\n')
            count++;

    fclose(fh);
    return count;
}
```

I am facing 2 problems (or more), file pointer not being accepted and the return value not being handled, any help is much appreciated (I am new to C programming).

Comment: Change `&fh` to `fh` in `pthread_create`. Also change `int *fh` to `void *arg` and then inside the function add `FILE *fh = arg;`

Comment: Call ```pthread_join()``` with ```(void **) &linecount```.

Comment: `printf("Could not open file %s", fh);` won't compile as fh is a int * in your code.  If you want both pass a struct, or better, do error checking in same scope where you do the open either in `main()` or in the thread.

Comment: Also, implicitly mention, but you are confusing open that returns int and fopen that returns a FILE *.

Comment: getc() returns an int not char (to be able to return EOF)

Comment: @kaylum it didn't work

Comment: "didn't work' is not helpful. What exactly did you change and what was the exact error/problem? You have many bugs in your code as pointed out in the other comments. Did you fix them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- MAX_FILE_NAME was not used.
- Manage resource in same scope.  I choose to do in `main()` here which in this case include `fopen()`, error check, and `fclose()`
- Changed signature on `*count_lines()` to match what `pthread_create()` expects.
- Changed type of c from char to int.
- Changed behavior to take file on command line to avoid having to create the file that code expects.
- I am getting a warning  `warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size` for `return (void *) count;` with `gcc -Wall -Wextra`.  Is there a better way to return a value?  Other than global variable, pass in arg with an out parameter for the value, or allocating something in the thread.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *count_lines(void *arg) {
    FILE *fh = (FILE *) arg;
    int c;
    int count = 0;
    while((c = getc(fh)) != EOF) {
        if(c == '\n') count++;
    }
    return (void *) count;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pthread_t thread_id;
    if(argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: %s path_of_flie\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *fh = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(!fh) {
        printf("Could not open file %s", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, count_lines, fh);
    int linecount;
    pthread_join(thread_id, (void **) &linecount);
    fclose(fh);
    printf("lines: %d \n", linecount);
}
```

and running the program on itself it returns:

```
lines: 32
```

Comment: it works, can you explain why you used `return (void *) count` instead of `return count`?

Comment: `pthread_create()` expects the type `void *(*start_routine) (void *)` so returning a `void *.  If you declare it returning and int and int I was getting warning `passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type`. If I declared `void *count_files(void *arg)` but `return count` then I would get the warning `returning ‘int’ from a function with return type ‘void *’ makes pointer from integer without a cast`